# filedset collapse issue in ExtJS

Tags: extjs4.1, fieldset

I Use ExtJS 4.1 and use `fieldset`, `collapsible: true,` but initialy it must be collpsed, so i set `collapsed: true`, but the `fieldset` is not rendered, and it trows error in consol` *Cannot call method 'getFrameInfo' of undefined*, 
[image]

can please someone tell me the reason of issue, and the solution?

Comment: most likely the issue is else where, post your code to get a better answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had exactly the same problem. The problem has something to do with the layout of your parent. Just set the layout parameter

```
align: 'stretch'
```

of your parent and it will work just fine.

[Here](http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?212047-ExtJS-4.1.0-FieldSet-has-a-bug#5) is a working example.